# Google Maps API - exceeded daily request quota for this API yet have only had 265 visitors?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I get this message: The Google Maps API server rejected your request. You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.

Despite the site not yet being indexable and only having had 265 visitors - it's hosted at wordpress.com so I can't access the site code at all. Site theme is Selma (is it because the theme developers have exceeded their total requests?).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, usage limits and calculation of quota usage varies by API as mentioned in [Usage limits and billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-limits). And as far as I understand from the documentation, usage limit is not calculated based on the number of visitors.

You can exceed the usage limits for the Google Maps APIs web services by:

- Sending too many requests per day.
- Sending requests too fast, i.e. too many requests per second.
- Sending requests too fast for too long or otherwise abusing the web service.
- Exceeding other usage limits, e.g. locations per request in the Elevation API.

Answer to additional queries regarding usage limits can be found in Google Maps APIs - [Frequently Asked Questions](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq).

Comment: then how we can solve this problem ???????? , i exactly read that 4 parameters almost everywhere , no one provided a proper solution for that ....

Answer (score 0):

Initially there is a limit of 1 request:

[image: call limit]

I had to "enable billing for this project" in order to increase the limit (even if you will never exceed the limit of free calls/m). Press the edit button next to the limit to find the link that takes you to the billing page.

Answer (score 0):

It was my understanding that 'keys' registered before the 11th June 2018 would be exempt from the changes and not require billing to be enabled.